# Cargo plugin not pasted war file in tomcat web apps location

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, cargo

We are using gradle cargo plugin to deploy war in local. But it didn't place war file in tomcat web app folder. What's wrong in my code.
We are using 'cargoStartLocal' but it didn't place ROOT.war in /tomcat/webapps.

My code is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-cargo-plugin:2.0.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.cargo'

cargo {
    containerId = 'tomcat7x'
    port = 8080

    deployable {
        file = new File('Root.war')
        context = 'ROOT'
    }

    local {
        homeDir = new File(tomcatHome)
        outputFile = new File('../build/output.log')
        timeout = 60000

        containerProperties {
            property 'cargo.tomcat.ajp.port', 8081
        }
    }
}
```

What I have to give in port number. Exactly tomcat port number or whatever else?

Comment: I believe Cargo creates some temporary directory when deploying your artifact. I wouldn't get too hung up on that. What's your actual problem? Can you call your app from the browser after the deployment? Do you really want to use `ROOT` in your URL?

Comment: @Benjamin Muschko  Default war is     ROOT right? If there is a ROOT.war in tomcat, then only I can access that project using localhost:8080. If war name is some thing different, like MyProject.war, then I have to access localhost:8080/MyProject right?. I use cargo plugin in eclipse. When I run cargoRunLocal, it shows build successful. But ROOT.war not generated in tomcat.webapps folder. It's my actual problem.

Comment: By setting `context = 'ROOT'` the URL would be `http://localhost:8080/ROOT` and not `http://localhost:8080/`. I still don't understand your problem though.

Comment: Ok. On thing, How can I assure cargo plugin works correctly. Without using browser 'http://localhost:8080/ROOT' .

Comment: You are using the "wrong" task for your purpose. You will need to use `cargoRunLocal`. `cargoStartLocal ` shuts down the server right away after finishing the task (see plugin documentation). Using the `-i` command line option give you more information.

Comment: It will not helpful. If I use 'cargoRunLocal' is there any fork option? How to move to next task? like run test case.

Comment: It would be great if you would formulate your requirements in your question. Otherwise, anyone reading your question will have to ask a lot of question. Yes, in that case you would use `cargoRunLocal`. I think it would be better if you'd ask your question on the Gradle forum. Also, please explain your concrete use case. I am still not sure what the actual issue is you are facing.